# Tableau - Combined 2 query into 1 as one unified report

Tags: sql, dbeaver, tableau-desktop

I got asked to bring the Tableau Netdue figure from A report to B. The goal is to eventually combine both A and B reports to avoid going back and forth between two reports, and present them in Tableau. Now A and B are two separate reports/workbooks.

Both queries & original reports look unidentical.

My question is what's my first step would be? Can I just **Union All**?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaT9O.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVMTK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By how much does the query differ between each of the reports?
A Union All might be an idea - just add a column to identify the source, but as you've said that both reports and queries are unidentical (typo given that you are exploring union's), a union will fail.

You could just as easily import one report to the other:
For this exercise, we'll be importing dashboard B into the workbook that contains dashboard A.

Right mouse the dashboard B tab and choose copy. Over to the dashboard A workbook, choose paste. Tableau will now complete the import and you'll now at least have both dashboards, their data sources and assets in the one workbook, ready for your phase 2 whatever you decide next.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a follow-up question - 
If I copy and paste the dashboard, it will have an entire dashboard B over to dashboard A. However, my goal is also to be able to change the filter. 

For example, right now I only have Product_type: A & B at dashboard A, but what I want to do is having product type C from dashboard B adding to dashboard A.